# "cannot be resolved or is not a field" -- android -- vogella tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i just did this tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.todo_edit);
```

in the last line **Eclipse** underlines the todo_edit and says: 
todo_edit cannot be resolved or is not a field

---

todo_edit is in my layout folder.

it does not start with a capital letter

i have not imported android.R

---

i dont get where the error might be. ( again: its not even my own code, it was made by professionals )

any ideas ?

Comment: The first thing to always try when your `R` file is giving you problems is to do a `Project clean` and `rebuild`

Comment: check in R.java.  Is there a "todo_edit" element?  If no, try build all on the project.

Comment: right, i forgot to say that i tried this as well

Comment: thanks for correcting my stupid link

Comment: clean and rebuild is the solution

Comment: Do you have any errors in your xml files?

Comment: no i dont see any errors there

Comment: clean and rebuild is the solution either it solves the problem or there is some error in any xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check your xml files is there any error

If it is not building R.java that means there is some error in any of your xml or manifest file check it deeply it wont build until then

1. check what recent change you did with xml
2. You can remove and re-add the recent added/changed xml file

Comment: i did not do any changes at all ... i only did exactly what is said in the tutorial.

Comment: but i do get these errors: ResXMLTree_node size (nil) is smaller than header size 0x812.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your screen, assuming you're using Eclipse, hit Project -> Clean...

Select the appropriate project if it prompts you, then hit Project -> Build All.

If this does not resolve the issue, there is either an error in one of your XML files or it really doesn't exist!

Comment: after i cleand and wanted to rebuild it does not generate my R.java any more. But there are no xml errors shown.

Comment: ResXMLTree_node size (nil) is smaller than header size 0x812. ... what does that mean ? i get alot of these

Comment: ...todos/res/layout/activity_todos_overview.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world'). ...todos/res/menu/todos_overview.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings'). that are the errors i get over and over again. I added the missing strings to strings.xml. But the Errors wont go away. –

Comment: OK thank you all very much, i just was too stupid to correct the errors. After rebuilding several times it finally works. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `todo_edit.xml` (and all other XML files) doesn't have errors. When there's an error in one of the resource files, the SDK can't generate the `R` file.

Also, try cleaning the project and/or hitting `Ctrl+B` to build it (it may so happen you have autobuild turned off).

Also, try `Ctrl+Shift+O` to sort out your imports - it should ask you which `R` you want to import.

Also, check that none of your resources (incl images) have any kind of improper characters in names. E.g. the SDK doesn't like it when there are hyphens in the names.

All else having failed, try restarting Eclipse - it's a pretty complex environment, so it's ok for it to sometimes go nuts.

Comment: ctrl shift 0 did nothing.

Comment: but i seem to have errors in the xml ... ResXMLTree_node size (nil) is smaller than header size 0x812.

Comment: i didnt see them because they are not displayed like the other errors ... only in console and not in the tree view on the left . sorry. but i cant fix these eighter :(

Comment: @user2664856 it is to auto import package it won't show what it did but it will add all packages which are required

Comment: wow, what,s that file? Also, i think it shouldn't have capital letters in the name either.

Comment: ...todos/res/layout/activity_todos_overview.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
    ...todos/res/menu/todos_overview.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').

that are the errors i get over and over again. I added the missing strings to strings.xml. But the Errors wont go away.

Comment: OK thank you all very much, i just was too stupid to correct the errors. After rebuilding several times it finally works. thanks alot.